# Tkinter Drag-and-Drop Window Objects Up or Down on Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop, draggable, tkinter-canvas

I make frames, stick a few widgets in them, then place them on a canvas. My goal is to be able to drag-and-drop these window objects around in an up or down fashion.

What I'm trying to do is, when the user clicks a grip and moves a window object either up or down, I want the window object immediately above or below it to move out of its way once a boundary threshold is reached.

The exactly functionality I'm trying to replicate with Tkinter can be seen here:
[jQuery Drag and Drop Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable)

[image: Draggable Visual Example]

For example, as I drag a window object upward, the blocks above it move downward once a boundary threshold is reached to fill the same coordinate slot below. The same type of concept applies to a downward movement. If I move downward, I want the blocks below to move up to take the place of the slots above as the currently selected window object moves.

**My Primary Question**: How do I get the above and below window object IDs **relative** to a current window object while it's in-motion?

Your first thought might be `self.canvas.find_above(item)` or `self.canvas.find_below(item)` but I haven't been able to figure out how to update the above and below window objects **relative** to the window object in-motion as it moves.

Your second thought might be tags. For example, add and remove tags as to the upper and lower objects with `addtag_above(tag, item)` or `addtag_below(tag, item)`. I tried this extensively and it's still a moot point because I can't update above and below tags while the moving window object is in-motion.

The most relevant part of the code (note: this is minimal on purpose, I have tried so many things and this question is already quite long):

```
  def StartMove(self, event):
    self.y = event.y
    self.cy = event.widget.nametowidget(event.widget.winfo_parent()).winfo_y()
    self.current = self.canvas.find_closest(10, self.cy)[0]

  def OnMotion(self, event):
    self.canvas.move(self.current, 0, event.y - 10)

  def StopMove(self, event):
    self.y = None
```

Full Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class DragAndDrop(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.block_count = 0

    self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Add', command=self.addblock)
    self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='new')

    self.container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.container.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container, width=200, height=450)
    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.container,
                                  orient='vertical',command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')

    self.container.bind('<Configure>', self.handle_scroll)

  def addblock(self):
    self.block = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bd=1, relief='solid')
    self.block.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.grip = tk.Label(self.block, bitmap="gray25")
    self.grip.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

    self.grip.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
    self.grip.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
    self.grip.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)

    self.canvas.create_window((0, (self.block_count*25)),
                              window=self.block, anchor="nw",
                              width=200, height=24)
    self.block_count += 1
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

  def handle_scroll(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

  def StartMove(self, event):
    self.y = event.y
    self.cy = event.widget.nametowidget(event.widget.winfo_parent()).winfo_y()
    self.current = self.canvas.find_closest(10, self.cy)[0]

  def OnMotion(self, event):
    self.canvas.move(self.current, 0, event.y - 10)

  def StopMove(self, event):
    self.y = None

root = tk.Tk()
app = DragAndDrop(root)
app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I tried this extensively and it's still a moot point because I can't update above and below tags while the moving window object is in-motion."_ - What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: When an upper or lower threshold is reached and it's time to make the switch, in the `OnMotion` event, I'm usually checking for a condition if some coordinate or index is higher or lower than another. When this is True, it's usually in a for loop so I have the challenge of executing the move one time while in a for loop, on top of the challenge of executing while the object is in-motion.  I change coordinates, canvas moves, and indices. Usually blocks either fly off the screen, or get caught behind other blocks, or make the move but is buggy and unreliable when I try to move another block.

Answer (score 2):

> **My Primary Question**: How do I get the above and below window object
>   IDs relative to a current window object while it's in-motion?

It seems to me the simplest solution is to start by generating a list of all blocks and their coordinates. Then, sort the list by Y coordinates. In your binding, find the last block in the list with a Y coordinate above the mouse, and the first object with a Y coordinate below the mouse.

Comment: This is exactly one of the many routes I've been down. I'll focus more on this route since you suggested it. I was using a `dict` to do this but the sorting feature is really key here so I'll use a list and see if I can finally figure this out!